# Google Play permission declaration form is unreachable

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Our app uses SMS permission. ( It is a must and yes we did not fill the permission declaration form before. )
Sadly the app has been pulled out of release by google this morning. 
Because we have to request this permission we tried to fill the declaration form but it is not reachable anymore.
When I try to reach the "Link1" I'm being redirected to "Link2". And I absolutely cannot see any declaration field in play store either.

What should I do?

Link1:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSexGxix-00xgnBhPLDvxwjbTcYqHB7enz-cQVJIY4zLuJpRtQ/viewform
Link2:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfbmF-9G249UDLJZpEvJpjgwP8rjvvLyWyNYnFPrsqYjMNckg/closedform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an APK **WITHOUT** the permissions you require & release it.
THEN, send an APK **WITH** the permissions you require & **BOM** you'll see the declaration forms. :)
Fill the forms & release your app.

Also make sure you don't have an issue in alpha, beta or internal release
( Which is not being pointed by the Google while trying to publish PROD ).
If so, you will not be able to publish PROD APK.
You have to solve the issue in those places first.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and my app got rejected because the previous permission were strored in Applcation bundle. I used the solution

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

Externally defined to remove the node of permission and it works

Answer (score 1):

The Permission Declaration Form is now directly available in the Google Play Console and no longer available through the Google docs
You can Find it under

- **Store Presence->AppContent->Permissions declaration form**

Answer (score 0):

When you try to upload new APK to store (You can choose Alpha, Beta or internal) they will show again you permission form. And you submit the form.

Comment: I did not receive any form until I uploaded a new APK without the permissions. :((